# Add Span to a Wordpress/Woocommerce Title

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce, title

I'm looking for a solution to add a  in a Wordpress/Woocommerce title, like in the example below :

```html
<h1>Chocolate spread 13 oz Nutella</h1>

<h1>Chocolate spread 13 oz <span class="superspan">Nutella</span></h1>
```

or

```html
<h1>Flower perfume Dior Paris</h1>

<h1>Flower perfume <span class="superspan">Dior Paris</span></h1>
```

I think it's technically complicated, knowing that the number of words in the span and before could be different from a title to another. So I figured out maybe to put an hyphen to separate these two parts (Chocolate spread 13 oz - Nutella)

Do you have any idea of specific code to achieve this ?

Thanks a lot !

I didn't find any code for this specific configuration

Comment: I would use js to grab whats after hyphen and wrap it in span

Comment: Could you please explain more on what you're trying to achieve? Maybe tell me the end result you want, I might be able to help you.

Comment: My goal is just to change the css for the words between the span, juste for a graphic aspect :) But I'm not an expert in dev tbh